# Как вызвать метод из класса без ссылки

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mvp, di

Есть приложение состоящее из библиотек классов, приложение WinForm в MVP немного исправленное под себя, + DI. Из View я передаю вызов в Presenter, где он обрабатывает его, и отправляет сначала в Service где перенаправляет в Infrasctructure, весь анализирующий код я хочу перенести в эту библиотеку. Проблема в том, что бы вернуть какие то значения, мне нужно вызвать метод из Presenter а я не могу создать ссылку на Presenter из Infrastructure так как это зациклит приложение, подскажите как можно решить эту проблему?

**UPD CODE**

Presenter.MainPresenter

```
class MainPresenter : IMainPresenter
{
    IBrService _br;
    public MainPresenter(IBrService br)
    {
      _br=br;
    }

    public void OnBrLoginClickEventRaised(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       _br.AuthorisationUser(Br.Default.Token);
    }
}
```

Service.BrService

```
public class BrService : IBrService
{
    private IBr _br;
    public BrService(IBr br)
    {
        _br = br;
    }

    public void AuthorisationUser(string token) => _br.AuthorisationUser(token);
}
```

Infrastructure.Br

```
public class Br : IBr
{
    public WebSocket _webSocketBr = new WebSocket(Resource.BrUrl);
    IMainService _mainService;

    public Br()
    {                  
        SubscribeToEventSetup();
    }

    public void SubscribeToEventSetup()
    {
        _webSocketBr.MessageReceived += CommonGetBrMessage;   
        _webSocketBr.Open();
    }

    public void CommonGetBrMessage(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex regexFunction = new Regex("\"msg_type\":\"[a-z_]+\"");

        switch (regexFunction.Matches(e.Message).Count != 0 ? regexFunction.Matches(e.Message)[0].Value : string.Empty)
        {
            case "\"msg_type\":\"authorize\"":
            BrAuthorize(e.Message);
            break;                  
        }
    }

    public void AuthorisationUser(string token)
    {
       AuthorizeRqt AuthorizeLogin = new AuthorizeRqt
       {
            authorize = token
       };
       _webSocketBr.Send(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(AuthorizeLogin));
    }

    private void BrAuthorize(string message)
    {
        //Вот здесь мне надо передать message в Presenter
    }
}
```

**UPD EVENT**

MainView

```
        public event EventHandler LoginBrClickEventRaised;
        private void ButtonBrLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHelpers.RaiseEvent(this, LoginBrClickEventRaised, e);
        }
```

event EventHandler LoginBrClickEventRaised; в IMainView

и сам хелпер для событий

```
 public static class EventHelpers
{
    public static void RaiseEvent(object objectRaisingEvent, 
                                  EventHandler eventHandlerRaised, 
                                  EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        eventHandlerRaised?.Invoke(objectRaisingEvent, eventArgs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем вы описываете код текстом, если можно просто приложить код?

Comment: Вам не удалось в своем вопросе ясно описать цепочку вызовов. Исправьте вопрос (под тегами есть надпись "Править"). Пока понятно лишь , что View -> Presenter -> Service -> Infrastructure.

Comment: @tym32167 код добавил

Comment: Такие вещи обычно делаются тасками (в случае асинхронных запросов) или событиями (верха - презентер подписывается на событие низа - инфраструктуры)

Comment: @tym32167 подскажите а как событие оформить в Service, там лишь идет передача вызова, событие ведь не передать

Comment: ну [вот](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Server/BEServer.cs), например, класс, который у меня стоит между сервером и UI, UI отправляет через него команды вниз, низы через него отправляют ответы вверх

Comment: Все равно до конца не понимаю как это реализовать в моем случае, добавил в описание как я реализовываю перенаправление с формы, но из за дурацкой реализации данные с формы приходится тащить со свойств...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Определимся с сообщением, что будем передавать снизу вверх

```
public class InfraEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public String Message {get;}

    public InfraEventArgs(String message)
    {       
        Message = message;
    }
}
```

Сервис внизу, допустим, просто будет сдать сообщение каждую секунду

```
public class Infra
{
    public event EventHandler<InfraEventArgs> MessageHandler;
    private void Invoke(string message) => MessageHandler?.Invoke(this, new InfraEventArgs(message));
    System.Threading.Timer _timer ;
    private void Callback(object state) => Invoke($"Message with payload {Guid.NewGuid()}");

    public Infra()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(Callback, null, 0, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public void Start() {_timer.Change(0, 1000);}
    public void Stop() {_timer.Change(0, Timeout.Infinite);}
}
```

Презентер подписывается на сообщения, запускает сервис и пишет сообщения в консоль

```
public class Presenter
{
    private Infra _infra;

    public Presenter(Infra infra)
    {   
        _infra = infra;     
    }

    public void Start() 
    {   
        _infra.MessageHandler+=InfraMessageRecieved;
        _infra.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {       
        _infra.Stop();
        _infra.MessageHandler-=InfraMessageRecieved;
    }

    private void InfraMessageRecieved(object sender, InfraEventArgs args) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Message);
    }
}
```

Запускается это все вот так

```
var infra = new Infra();
var presenter = new Presenter(infra);

presenter.Start();  
Console.ReadLine();
presenter.Stop();
```

Вывод в консоль происходит, значит, сообщение снизу доезжает до презентера

```
Message with payload 54a39438-c913-4875-b2a0-620d0bc7922b
Message with payload 8b603f62-c9ba-4eaf-952a-09491e548b75
Message with payload a587fee0-2487-4de1-9071-a15dfade70f1
Message with payload 05770d5c-e8bc-4747-9c48-a255b6180111
Message with payload f6462a41-83e1-4fd2-943a-c71961ad8050
Message with payload 22c2c132-9959-4d83-972f-f7588948470d
Message with payload ac145f74-afe3-4426-8a04-53176d4d89b1
Message with payload f73f1648-c3dc-42aa-8642-5a5b10663595
Message with payload 1fef5193-1532-4e2a-b285-38e1b8c6dd80
```

Comment: Так все же, как мне перенаправить само событие _infra.MessageHandler по сервису, если у него фактически нет тела и вызова. public event EventHandler<InfraEventArgs> MessageHandler // Событие никогда не используется

Comment: @Unnamed что значит не используется? А это в презентере что такое? `_infra.MessageHandler+=InfraMessageRecieved;` В представленном коде выше презентер командует сервисом, сервис реагирует событиями - это двунаправленный поток, что вам не хватает?

Comment: Мне все хватает, ошибка в программе написана) Тем более у вас реализация без сервиса, у меня же как я показывал выше между двумя классами стоит сервис

Comment: Или наоборот напрямую без сервиса работать как у меня в формах реализовано? Но тогда все в статик придется переводить

Comment: @Unnamed Я показал вам, как подружить класс A с классом B и как настроить их взаимодействие A<->B. Что делать с классом посередине - вам решать, хотите сделайте A<->C<->B, (вам моего ответа хватит для этого), хотите - делайте так, как я сделал [по ссылке](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Server/BEServer.cs), что вам дал - там как раз класс посередине стоит между нижним и верхним слоем. Вы же не думаете, что я буду за вас писать вам код для конкретно вашей задачи? Я вам дал пример, поймите как он работает и тогда сможете решить вашу проблему сами.

Comment: спасибо вам, нет конечно я не жду прямого ответа, просто хотелось понять как вы использовали A<->C<->B, просто вот такой вызов _infra.MessageHandler+=InfraMessageRecieved; я не смогу реализовать, так как мне надо будет обратиться к классу С за MessageHandler, но там MessageHandler находится в формате  public event EventHandler<InfraEventArgs> MessageHandler, и как я говорил выше, ошибка о том что событие не используется, само перенаправление я как понял у вас реализовано вот так var handler = BanLog; handler?.Invoke(this, message);

Comment: @Unnamed смотрте, я вам показал как сделать A<->B. То есть как связать 2 класса вы знаете. У вас 3 класса, то есть вы можете связать A<->B, а потом свзяать B<->C и у ваc получится A<->B<->C - то, что вам надо